# SonarQube on Kubernetes with LDAP authentication

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, sonarqube

I'm having issues opening up communication with my LDAP authentication. Locally logins work fine, but when running on Kubernetes I am receiving the error:

```
2018.10.03 18:23:44 INFO  web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
2018.10.03 18:23:44 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com, request=(&amp;(mail={0})(objectclass=person)), realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}
2018.10.03 18:23:45 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Groups will not be synchronized, because property 'ldap.group.baseDn' is empty.
2018.10.03 18:23:45 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection: FAIL
2018.10.03 18:23:45 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to open LDAP connection
    at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.testConnection(LdapContextFactory.java:211)
    at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapRealm.init(LdapRealm.java:63)
```

I'm a bit unsure how to open up the flow from the Kubernetes cluster to ldap.

Comment: Where are you running your Kubernetes cluster? Can you describe your environment in detail?

Comment: I'm running it on public bluemix using the image from the docker repository. Just modified my sonar.properties file with

sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldaps://urlhere:636
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=***,o=***.com
ldap.user.request=(&(mail={0})(objectclass=person))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

I blocked out some spots but that is what is in my properties file. Works no problem when running locally on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I totally think it's either an 'Egress' firewall rule not allowing your Kubernetes cluster to talk to port `636` or an 'Incoming' firewall rule on your LDAP deployment not allowing the external IP address range of your Kubernetes cluster into port `636`.

[This might help](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_firewall.html#firewall) where it says "Allowing the cluster to access infrastructure resources and other services"

Comment: I did come across this, it does seem helpful and what I am looking for! It just seems a bit unclear where I make these adjustments to allow for outgoing traffic to my ldap location. I took a look around Kubernetes and on the console for Bluemix and have not seen anything relating to this.